# netstat showing multiple responses for single listening process

Tags: ssh, shell, netstat

Why does `netstat -lntp` show multiple responses as `0.0.0.0:22` & `:::22` for a single `sshd` process?

```
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address               Foreign Address             State       PID/Program name   
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22                  0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      1179/sshd    
tcp        0      0 :::22                       :::*                        LISTEN      1179/sshd
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest answer is `0.0.0.0:22` is an IPv4 address and `:::22` is an IPv6 address. If are using GNU `netstat` version 1.42—or something similar—you only want the IPv4 results just use the `-4` flag like this:

```
netstat -lntp4 22
```

And if you only want the IPv6 results just use the `-6` flag like this:

```
netstat -lntp6 22
```

The version of `netstat` installed on the version of BSD used by systems like Mac OS X would use a command something like this for IPv4:

```
netstatnetstat -p tcp -f inet | grep 22
```

And this for IPv6:

```
netstatnetstat -p tcp -f inet6 | grep 22
```